# MVC 5 Retrieving Data from SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, navigation, sql-server-2012

Could somebody please explain how I retrieve a simple set of records from a SQL Server 2012 database to display on an ASP.NET page? I have tried following some tutorials but I am missing something and I cant see the wood for the trees.

I have a connection string in the `web.config` file:

```
 <add name="DefaultConnection" 
      connectionString="Data Source=MY-LAPTOP;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True" 
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I have a class called `Navigation.cs` which is:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public partial class Navigation
    {
        public int navigation_ID { get; set; }
        public string title_TV { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> position_IV { get; set; }
        public bool main_BT { get; set; }
        public string url_TV { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have a `Shared/_layout.cshtml` page which has the following code:

```
@model List<WebApplication1.Models.Navigation>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.title_TV)</li>
}
```

I also have a controller called `HomeController.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following error

> An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in App_Web_wqu1n0vj.dll but was not handled in user code.

I have created a class called `TestEntities.cs` which is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;

namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public partial class TestEntities : DbContext
    {
         public TestEntities()
        : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Navigation> Navigations { get; set; }
}
```

}

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Comment: You should also have a class that derives from `DbContext` - that class will define what **connection string** is being used, and from the error message I'd guess it's not using the `DefaultConnection` you have (but something else)

Comment: I have added a new class, please see the amended post, unfortunately I am still getting the same error.